# retrieve action message on multiple action classes in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am developing one java project using struts2 and hibernate
i have one super action class name it as ProjAction where in that project management every event will come across the main Super Class.
i have one child action class name it as saveDataAction after saving the data it goes to the super action class and gives the result.
So upto to the Super action class i can able to display the action message using the store interceptor in struts2 config file for its respective action class results. i have used the operationMode as 'AUTOMATIC'

NOW to avoid the refresh issue i have one action class name it as ProjRedirectAction. So in this action class i am not able to show/retrieve the action message after saving the data

can anyone tell me how to access the action message in ProjRedirectAction class using store interceptor. or else is there any way to show the action message to multiple action classes of struts2.

```
    public class SuperAction extends ActionSupport {
    public String getData() {
    //implementation for showing the data in the jsp page
    //the result is always redirect to some default.jsp
    return SUCCESS;
    }
    //private method which accessed by its child class for redirecting to superclass
   public String nextCall() {
   //few implementation done after that it calls the getData() method
   return getData();
   }
   }

//Child Class implementaion for ex saving records in db
public class ChildAction extends SuperAction {
public String saveData() {
//saving data to db and then calling the return nextCall method of superACtion class
return nextCall();
}
}
```

//earlier i had this implementation, the reason being adding one more action class in my project is to avoid refresh issue(on refresh the same value was inserting to DB) so i have added one more action class with name RedirectAction

//RedirectACtion class implementation

```
public class RedirectAction {
public String execute() {
//this method is having same implementation as the method getData() of SuperAction class includes
return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

//struts.xml config

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
//SuperACtion class result
<action name="*Super" method="{1}" class="com.action.SuperAction">
<interceptor-ref name="store">
<param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<result name="SUCCESS" type="redirectAction">executeRedirect</result>
</action>

//ChildACtion class result
<action name="*Child" method="{1}" class="com.action.ChildAction">
<interceptor-ref name="store">
<param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<result name="SUCCESS" type="redirectAction">executeRedirect</result>
</action>

//RedirectACtion class result
<action name="*Redirect" method="{1}" class="com.action.RedirectAction">
<interceptor-ref name="store">
<param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">Default.jsp</result>
</action>
```

this issue i am not finding any solution , any help is really appriciated
thank you

Comment: Show your code and action configurations.

Comment: @AleksandrM i have added the code above, kindly check and let me know if u have any doubt. i didn find any solution on stack overflow with this kind of issue

Comment: There is no `store` interceptor in your configuration. There is no `executeRedirect` action in your configuration. Don't mess with the default values -> `SUCCESS` in struts.xml should be `success` and in action just `return SUCCESS;`.